# How to add a mathematical notation into html document (inline)

Tags: html, mathml

How can I write mathematical notation (ital, sub/sup script, greek letters) in and html page. I need this letters to be inline. I tried wrapping them with `<MI></MI>` or `<MATH></MATH>` but it didn't work. 
Is mathml need some additional software installed on the server or additional browser feature?

Thanks

Comment: Do not **rape** them please with anything .. you can try **wrapping** them, though.. :p

Comment: @Gaby I'm more interested in the MathML rap. Could be a hit.

Comment: @lonesomeday, hehe.. dirty associations are first in my processing list.. MathML rap could be a hit indeed, though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in markup, you'll need MathML.  However, browser support is *very* limited.

Currently, the only major browser to support it is Firefox.

You can test whether your browser supports it [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjqXY/) (code borrowed from [the Wikipedia article on MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML#Embedding_MathML_in_HTML5_files)).

[This site](http://www.dessci.com/en/reference/mathml/default.htm) has what seems to be a pretty decent introduction to the syntax of MathML, if you aren't familiar with it.

Comment: Got it, I'm using symbol entities instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MathJax javascript library. The [Math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) site uses it too.

http://www.mathjax.org/